# Login and Clicking Buttons with Python "requests" Module

Tags: python, selenium, httprequest, bots, httpresponse

I have been playing with **requests module** on Python for a while as part of studying **HTTP requests/responses**; and I think I grasped most of the fundamental things on the topic that are supposed to be understood. With a naive analogy it basically works on ping-pong principle. You send a request in a packet to server and then it send back to you another packet. For instance, logging in to a site is simply sending a **post request** to server, I managed to do that. However, what I have trouble is to fail clicking on buttons through **HTTP post request**. I searched for it here and there, but I could not find a valid answer to my inquiry other than utilizing **selenium module**, which is what I do not want to if there is another way with **requests module** too. I am also aware of the fact that they created such a module called **selenium** for a thing.

**QUESTIONS:**

**1)** What kind of parameters do I have to take into account for being able to click on buttons or links from the account I accessed through HTTP requests? For instance, when I watch network activity for request header and response header with my browser's built-in inspect tool, I get so many parameters sent back by server, e.g. sec-fetch-dest, sec-fetch-mode, etc.

**2)** Is it too complicated for a beginner or is there too much advanced stuff going on behind the scene to do that so **selenium** was created for that reason?

Comment: It really depends on the webpage - is it a fancy, modern single page application where everything is handled by JavaScript? Or is it a basic HTML page with inputs inside of forms? If it's the latter, you would just have to formulate a POST request to simulate a button press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, you could write a program to do this with requests, but you would be duplicating much of the functionality that is already built and optimized in other tools and APIs. The general process would be:

1. Load the HTML that is normally rendered in your browser using a get request.
2. Process the HTML to find the button in question.

Then, if it's a simple form:

1. Determine the request method the button will carry out (e.g. using the `formmethod` argument, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)).
2. Perform the specified request with the required information in your request packet.

If it's a complex page (i.e. it uses JavaScript):

1. Find the button's unique identifier.
2. Process the JavaScript code to determine what action is performed when the button is clicked.
3. If possible, perform the JavaScript action using requests (e.g. following a link or something like that). I say if possible because JavaScript can do many things that, to my knowledge, simple HTTP request cannot, like changing rendered CSS in order to change the background color of a `<div>` when a button is clicked.

You are much better off using a tool like [selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) or [beautiful soup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/), as they have created APIs that do a lot of the above for you. If you've used the built-in requests library to learn about the basic HTTP request types and how they work, awesome--now move on to the plethora of excellent tools that wrap requests up into a more functional and robust API.